# How do I parse this json response object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, parsing

I have a json response of the following type:

```
[{
  cat_name : value
  post : [{
          title:value
          image:value
          content:value
         },
         {
          title:value
          image:value
          content:value
         },
         {
          title:value
          image:value
          content:value
         }]
 },{
  cat_name : value
  post : [{
          title:value
          image:value
          content:value
         },
         {
          title:value
          image:value
          content:value
         }]
 },
{
 cat_name : value
 post : [{
         title:value
         image:value
         content:value 
         }]
}]
```

and so on...

I've tried the following -

Stored the response object in an array(responseArray). Implemented first for loop from 0 till responseArray.count, stored the value for post in an array (postArray). Inside the first loop I implemented the second loop from 0 till postArray.count and returned the value for count of postarray.count.

**EDIT - ADDED THE FOR LOOP**

```
for (int i = 0; i < responseArrayList.count; i++) {

    postArrayList = [[responseArrayList objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"post"];

    for (int j = 0; j < postArrayList.count; j++) {

        return postArrayList.count;

    }
}
```

It gives a warning that the second loop wont be incremented and would only run once.

How do I set the return value for numberOfRowsInSection ?

Comment: all the "values" are strings which I have to make use of in the tableview method, cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: please add your code

Comment: Check the question, I edited and added the for loop

Comment: please add your more code of numberPfRowInSection and cellForRow method

Answer (score 0):

Remove line from second for loop

return postArrayList.count;

If your method wants to return something then add return statement outside of for loop.

Comment: I shifted the return statement outside of the for loop and its running. 
Now in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method I tried setting the text and image (I have an imageview and a label in the prototype cell) inside and also outside the for loop (the same for loop I used in the numberOfRows method). Here the app is crashing

Comment: When used outside the error says - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleObjectArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000018920

And when used inside the error says - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000305100

Comment: @AkshayYerneni This is crash issue due to some other code. Can you please put code here?

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface TableViewController ()

@property(nonatomic)NSArray *responseArrayList;

@end
```

Convert to JSON object and store it in your global variable

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   myJsonString = //here your JSON string response;
   self.responseArrayList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myJsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]options:0 error:NULL];
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
       return self.responseArrayList.count;    
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     NSArray *postArrayList = [[responseArrayList objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"post"];
     return postArrayList.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to write code like this...

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

     self.myarray=dict[@"result”][@“post”];

//store the value in newObject

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        NSLog(@"%@ my object is ",obj);
        myobject  *object = [[myobject alloc]init];
        object.name = obj.productName;
        object.image = obj.productimage;

        [_myarray addObject:object];

    }];
```